# Failed to resolve firebase-messaging and common - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I am getting this errors while building the project.

1. Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging
2. Failed to resolve: common

I am not getting any solution for this on stackoverflow. Please check the code and let me know the issue.

This issue came after importing project to Android Studio.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    //buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abcd.xyzzz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id : "65f1XXXXXXXXc4-9e41-XXX",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "916298XXXXXXXX"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // applovin
    implementation project(':unity-ads')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.jackpocket:scratchoff:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.33.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.7.0.1@jar'
    //compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:2.1.1.0' //not used
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.9.1]'
    implementation files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.7.0-javadoc.jar')
    implementation files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.7.0.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

In order to use Firebase Cloud Messaging, you need to add the corresponding dependency. So please also add this new line of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) more informations.

Comment: Tried it......... but getting even more errors after changing the versions

Comment: @AlexMamo Aren't the version of all the firebase related services supposed to be the same?

Comment: @sHOLE No, not anymore.

Comment: @sHOLE Please take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) where you'll find all the latest versions. Cheers!

Comment: @AlexMamo Will do. Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am getting this error today, even I don't use any firebase dependency on my project (I use OneSignal)